# Why git status said I'm on master branch, but git branch shows nothing?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently studying about basic concept of git, and creating a local git repository on my machine. And I just curious, why when I use `git branch` shows nothing but when I use `git status`, git said that I'm on branch `master`?. I'm expecting when I run `git branch`, there is `master` branch displayed

What I did are :

```
mkdir my-app
cd my-app
touch README.md
git init
git config user.email "my_email"
git config user.name "my_name"
git checkout -b master
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git branch
```

Here's some screenshoot :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you don't understand basic Git commands, or even what Git is (it sounds like you don't), here's a tutorial I've recently published: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/. Special attention is paid to understanding what `git status` means.

Comment: OK so could you please clarify the question? What's wrong? Is it the output of `git branch`? If so, what _is_ the output of `git branch`? And please show text, not pictures, when you are displaying code (including what you said to Git and what Git said to you). Select, copy, and paste from the Terminal into your question.

Comment: And please don't edit the question to include the answer. Answer your question as an _answer_ (or accept another answer that says the same thing).

Comment: @matt: This is one of those rare cases where it *has* to be an image, as the problem is the black-on-black font. :-)

Comment: @matt Thanks for the link, your article is great. If I may indulge into some (very) minor nitpicking though, you write "The most recent commit is HEAD but you can omit that. For example, to see the contents of b.txt in the most recent commit: `$ git show :b.txt`
" ....but this is showing the file as it is in the index, not in last commit. Again, *very* minor.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you, I will recheck that!

Comment: @torek if the OP had copied and pasted to start with, the question would have been answered before it was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the output of `git branch` is

```
* master
```

...but that you cannot *see* the word `master` because something is wrong with the color display settings in the Terminal / shell you're using.

Comment: I just realized that.... exactly before I open this thread again. Okay I think my question is solved..

Comment: If my guess / answer is right, please accept it and let's close this out and leaves things in a state where this could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch` is used to list, create, or delete branches whereas `git status` is used to show the working tree status.

You can refer the git reference [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/) for details regarding git commands.